# Intermediate value theorem for concave functions

Tags: real-analysis

**I'm studying to get into a Master's degree in Pure Mathematics in Brazil and I came across this question::**

We say that $f : I \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is concave if for every $x,y \in I$ and $t \in [0,1]$

$$f(tx + (1-t)y) \ \geq \ tf(x) + (1-t)f(y).$$

Let $f : [a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ concave and continuous, with f(a) < f(b). Show that for every $d \in (f(a),f(b))$ exists a unique $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c) = d.$

**I couldn't begin to resolve this issue. As always, I thought about assuming absurdly that there are $c,c' \in (a,b)$ such that $f(c) = f(c') = d$ but I didn't find any contradiction.**

Sugestions?

Comment: Can you show that there is *at least* one solution $c$ such that $f(c) = d$?

Comment: @MartinR I know there is at least one solution by the Intermediate Value Theorem. The problem for me is to show that the solution is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that there are two solutions $a < c < c' < b$ with $f(c) = f(c') = d < f(b)$. Then $c' = t c + (1-t) b$ for some $t \in (0, 1)$ and therefore
$$
 d = f(c') \ge t f(c) + (1-t) f(b) > tf(c) + (1-t)f(c) = f(c) = d \, 
$$
which is not possible.

Geometrically speaking, the graph of $f$ lies above the secant joining $(c, f(c))$ and $(b, f(b))$ which has a positive slope, so that $f(x) > f(c)$ for all $x \in (c, b)$.